# Ignore data coming in to TCP socket

Tags: sockets, posix

Some protocols like HTTP can specify a message length, then send a (possibly very long) message. No other messages can be received while this message is being sent (something HTTP/2.0 tried to solve) so if you decide to ignore the message, you can't just continue waiting for messages and not pull its data.

Normally I read() up to the length of the message repeatedly into a junk buffer and just ignore the bytes. But that involves copying possibly millions of bytes from kernelspace into userspace (at 1 copy per memory page, so not millions of copies). Isn't there some way to just tell the kernel to discard the bytes instead of providing them?

It seemed like an obvious question, but the only answer I've been able to come up with is oddly resource heavy, either using splice() to dump the bytes into a pipe and seeking the pipe back to 0, or opening "/dev/null" and using sendfile() to send the bytes there. I could do that, and reserve a (single) file descriptor for flushing data out of clogged connections, without reading, but isn't there just a... ignore(descriptor, length) function?

Comment: "*Since version 2.4, Linux supports the use of MSG_TRUNC in the flags argument of recv(2) (and recvmsg(2)). This flag causes the received bytes of data to be discarded, rather than passed back in a caller-supplied buffer.*" - http://linux.die.net/man/7/tcp ?

Comment: 'No other messages can be received while this message is being sent' is untrue. You can use another connection. There is no way to discard the data other than closing the socket.

Comment: Note that using `MSG_TRUNC` as an input flag for `recv()` is not portable, it only works on Linux, not other platforms.